# jQuery - Removing all anchor tags with a specific class from a div

Tags: jquery

In certain cases, and for reasons that go beyond the scope of this question, the anchors are getting repeated. Here's a sample div:

```
<div class="unifyRepeat listing">
    <a class="businessAnchor" name="abcchildcareandlearningcenter"></a>
    <a class="businessAnchor" name="abcchildcareandlearningcenter"></a>
    <a class="businessAnchor" name="abcchildcareandlearningcenter"></a>
    <a class="businessAnchor mceItemAnchor" name="abcchildcareandlearningcenter"></a>
    <table class="tblListing">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="bold">ABC Child Care and Learning Center</p>
                    <p>Jane Smith</p>
                    <p>(555) 555-1234</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src="images/ABCchildcare.jpg">
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a class="linkToTop" href="#top">^ Top</a>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery that appends the anchor and attempts to remove any existing ones:

```
$('#businessListings div.listing').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find('p:first').text(),
        cleanedName = name.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();

    $('ul#businessListingLinks').append('<li><a href="#' + cleanedName + '">' + name + '</a>');

    var anchor = '<a class="businessAnchor" name="' + cleanedName + '"></a>';
    $(this).remove('a.businessAnchor');
    //$(this).each('a.businessAnchor').remove();
    $(this).prepend(anchor);
});
```

I thought that the remove() line would select **all** anchor tags with the class "businessAnchor", but it's not.

As you can see, I tried the each() function, but that didn't work. I'm not sure if that's because I didn't implement it properly, or some other reason.

Comment: I think you should be trying to stop the script from producing repeats rather than just removing them. Using `.remove()` *should* remove all the elements in the jQuery object, maybe try putting it *after* you have prepended the element?

Comment: `$(this).find('a.businessAnchor').remove();`

Comment: where's the id? your calling to `#businessListings` but its not in the html you provided

Comment: `#businessListings` is missing O3O

Comment: If you want to all element with a class, use `$('.class-name').remove()`

Comment: To those mentioning the #businessListings ID missing: The element with ID of #businesListings is a parent div of the sample div. That's necessary to select all divs within that #businessListings div and sets the context of $(this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).find('a.businessAnchor').remove();
```

Since, from the markup, it seems that `a.businessAnchor` are direct child of div, so you can do this too:

```
$(this).children('a.businessAnchor').remove();
```

Comment: That did the trick, Palash! Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I can (said I have to wait 10 mins to mark as an answer).